# Extjs 4 Uncaught TypeError

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to do something like: when user click on the button, the child panel will show/hide

but when i press on the button i get this error message :

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'child'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of things you need to refer to your child panel by it's 'id' which I guess is 'p' from your code above.

So you'd want something like this:

```
function: onbtnClick(show) {

    var childPanel = Ext.getCmp('p');
    if(show) {
        childPanel.show();
    } else {
        childPanel.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Oxi This is a cleaner solution then mine. However, there is some dangers to using an `id` config that you should be aware of. So as not to complication things, once you get this all straightened out you should take a look at [this](http://softdevbuilttolast.wordpress.com/2012/06/20/extjs-avoid-using-the-id-property-unless-you-have-to/).

Comment: @Geronimo Thank you so much ! i didn't know that before. by the way I am having another issue :(

Comment: @Oxi if it is disrelated you should ask another Q.

Comment: @Geronimo yeah I was going to post about something along the lines of btn.up or similar, but didn't have enough time to examine Oxi's structure and desired behaviour to give an all encompassing solution